# Keras model evaluation accuracy unchanged, and designing model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to design a CNN in Keras to classify small images of emojis in other images. Below is an example of one of the 13 classes. All images are the same size and all the emojis are of the same size as well. I would think that one should rather easily be able to achieve VERY high accuracy when classifying, as emojis from one class is exactly the same! My intuition told me that if an emoji is 50x50 I could create a convolutional layer of the same size to match one type of emoji. My supervisor did not think that was feasible however. Anyway, my problem is that, no matter how I design my model, I always get the same validation accuracy for each epoch, which corresponds to 1/13 (or simply guessing that each emoji belongs to the same class).

My model looks like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=IMG_SIZE))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
#model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten()) 
#model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax', name="Output"))
```

And I train it like this:

```py
# ------------------ Compile and train ---------------
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
rms = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.004, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])  # TODO Read more about this
train_hist = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_steps=validation_generator.n // BATCH_SIZE,  # TODO que?
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    #callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)]
)
```

Even with this model, that has over 200 million parameters, I get exactly 0.0773 in validation accuracy for each epoch:

```
Epoch 1/10
56/56 [==============================] - 21s 379ms/step - loss: 14.9091 - acc: 0.0737 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 2/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.9308 - acc: 0.0737 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 3/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.7869 - acc: 0.0826 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 4/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.8948 - acc: 0.0759 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 5/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 109ms/step - loss: 14.8897 - acc: 0.0762 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 6/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 109ms/step - loss: 14.8178 - acc: 0.0807 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 7/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 15.0747 - acc: 0.0647 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 8/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.7509 - acc: 0.0848 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 9/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.8948 - acc: 0.0759 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
Epoch 10/10
56/56 [==============================] - 6s 108ms/step - loss: 14.8228 - acc: 0.0804 - val_loss: 14.8719 - val_acc: 0.0773
```

Because its not learning anything, I'm starting to think that it's not my models fault, but maybe the dataset or how I train it. I have tried training with "adam" as well but get the same result. I try to change the input size of the images but still, same result. Below is a sample from my dataset. Do you guys have any ideas what could be wrong?

[image: Same from dataset]

Comment: i think your training dataset is too small for such a heavy model with so many parameters. i would suggest using transfer learning, use pre-trained mobilenet from tf keras and train just one fc layer using your data. it should do above 90%

Comment: Can you try removing dropout after first layer?

Comment: I tried removing the dropout layer, but nothing changed. @ankesh I'm currently trying to boost my dataset to 200 images per class...

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue currently is that your model has way too many parameters relative to how few samples you have for training. For image classification nowadays, you generally want to just have conv layers, a Global*Something*Pooling layer, and then a single Dense layer for your outputs. You just need to make sure that your conv section ends up with a large enough receptive field to be able to find all the features you need.

The first thing to think about is making sure that you have a large enough receptive field ([further reading about that here](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807)). There are three main ways to achieve that: pooling, stride >= 2, and/or dilation >= 2. Because you have only 13 "features" that you want to identify, and all of them will always be pixel-perfect, I'm thinking dilation will be the way to go so that the model can easily "overfit" on those 13 "features". If we use 4 conv layers with dilations of 1, 2, 4, and 8, respectively, then we'll end up with a receptive field of 31. This should be enough to easily recognize 50-pixel emoji.

Next, how many filters should each layer have? Normally, you start with a few filters, and increase as you go through the model, as you are doing here. However, we want to "overfit" on specific features, so we should probably increase the amounts in the earlier layers. Just to make it easy, let's give all layers 64 filters.

Last, how do we convert this all to a single prediction? Rather than using a dense layer, which would use a *ton* of parameters and would not be translation invariant, people nowadays use GlobalAveragePooling or GlobalMaxPooling. GlobalAveragePooling is more common, because it's good for helping to find combinations of many features. However, we just want to find 13 or so exact features here, so GlobalMaxPooling might work even better. Then a single dense layer after that will be enough to get a prediction. Because we're using *Global*MaxPooling, it doesn't need to be flattened first—global pooling already does that for us.

Resulting model:

```
Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=IMG_SIZE)
Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=2, activation="relu")
Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=4, activation="relu")
Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=8, activation="relu")
GlobalMaxPooling()
Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax', name="Output")
```

Try that. You'll probably also want to add BatchNormalization layers in there after every layers except the last. Once you get decent training accuracy, check if it's overfitting. If it is (which is likely), try these steps:

- batch norm if you haven't already
- weight decay on all conv and dense layers
- SpatialDropout2D after the conv layers and regular Dropout after the pooling layer
- augment your data with an ImageDataGenerator

Designing nets like this is almost more of an art than a science, so change stuff around if you think you should. Eventually, you will get an intuition for what is more or less likely to work in any given situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for that great reply! I'll do a bit of reading. I tested your network, with and without BatchNormalization, but to no avail. Still getting the same accuracy of 0.07 :(

Comment: @Zorobay That makes me suspect that the issue might lie in the data, not the model. At least one of our models should have been able to learn _something_.